# Movement in 2D Map in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x

I'm remaking my battle system for my text-based RPG and one of the core things are missing. I have code like this:

```
gamemap=[["player", "", "", "", "", ""], 
["", "", "", "", "", ""], 
["", "", "", "", "", ""], 
["", "", "", "", "", ""], 
["", "", "", "", "", ""], 
["", "", "", "", "", "enemy"]]


while True:
    print("╔▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╗")
    for i in gamemap:
        print("▒║", end=" ")
        for o in i:
            if o=="player":
                print("⌂", end="")
            if o=="enemy":
                print("⦿", end="")
            if o=="":
                print(".", end="")
        print("  ║▒ ")

    print("╚▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╝")


    #shows possible actions

    print("")
    print("    UP       |     ATTACK")
    print("LEFT   RIGHT | DEFEND   SPELL")
    print("    DOWN     |     QUICK")

    #asks what player wants to do
    act=str(input("Type here. "))

    if act=="RIGHT":
        ...
```

If you run this program, it will show what my game looks like. That house-like character is player and orb is an enemy. Here is my broblems:

A) I want that player can move. So if player would type RIGHT, it would move right by one point. How i could possibly do that?

B) And other thing that you can answer if you can/want to. I would like to detect distance between player and enemy to int variable "distance". It would be handy with battle system later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gamemap is a grid (or matrix). Try to split the game-logic and the rendering-logic from each other. What I mean is; give your player and your enemy more info. An easy way is something like the following:

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, x, y, char, name):
        self.pos = (x, y)
        self.char = char
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.char
    def up(self):
        y = max(self.pos[1] - 1, 0)
        self.pos = (self.pos[0], y)
    def right(self, width):
        # not as nice, as up, as the width has to be
        # known for the boundaries.
        x = (self.pos[0] + 1) % width
        self.pos = (x, self.pos[1])
    # make something like this for every direction. problem:
    #  needs size of matrix for outer-bounds

player = Entity(0, 0, "⌂", "player")
enemy = Entitiy(5, 5, "⦿", "enemy")

def render(entities, width, height):
    # just basics, no borders etc. for now
    matrix = [['.' for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
    for entity in entities:
        x, y = entity.pos
        matrix[y][x] = str(entity)   # or entity.char, if unclear
    printable = '\n'.join(''.join(line) for line in matrix)
    print(printable)

# call with
>>> render([player, enemy], 6, 6)
⌂.....
......
......
......
......
.....⦿
>>> player.down()
......    
⌂.....
......
......
......
.....⦿
```

This is not the best solution, as the entities are hard-wired. I would suggest a `Matrix`-class, holding these structures and managing the printed matrix as well.

For your second question: As with the above solution you would have the entities position in a coordinate system, different approaches are possible to get a distance.

**[Euklidian geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry):**

```
import math
a = max(player.pos[0]-enemy.pos[0], enemy.pos[0]-player.pos[0]) # on x-axis (dunno, if abs would do the same)
b = max(player.pos[1]-enemy.pos[1], enemy.pos[1]-player.pos[1]) # on y-axis
distance = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

**[Manhattan-metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry):**

```
aX, aY = player.pos
bX, bY = enemy.pos
distance = abs(aX - bX) + abs(aY - bY)
```

If I got something wrong or you got questions: go ahead and tell me :P

**EDIT**

- added `Entity.right` to illustrate vertical movement and matrix-boundaries.

Comment: Only one thing left... i tried your code and it worked perfectly! I made 'move down' -function for Entity class and it worked, but i don't know how to make right/left -_-' i tried to edit up/down to vertical functions but they act just acted weirdly. i'm pretty n00b at class things ^ ^'

Comment: I added `Entity.right` so you might get the idea. If you are new to classes, read up about [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). That's the main paradigma behind classes (not only in Python) and might give you a better understanding. You may also want to try various online-courses as [Codecadamy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python) (no advertisement inteded) to learn more about all that. :)